# Getting error as "Objects are not valid as React child"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'am working React weather project, in which by inputting the city and country values, the information is loaded on screen. The amin file App.js is function component and getting above mentioned error after submitting the values.

Following are the files for reference

1. App.js (here getWeather() is created)

[image]
2. Weather.js 
[image]
3. App.js (Component created here)
[image]

4. Error I'am getting

[image]

Comment: I'd be careful using multiple conditions with `{condition1 && condition2 && <JSX />}`. I've ran into situations where the component was rendered when both conditions weren't true. I'd also check every value you're trying to render because the most likely cause of this is if you are trying to render an object like `{object}` when you think it's a string.

Comment: What `setCity` function does? And how do you define it?

Answer (score 1):

Aparently your 'city' props is a Object, not a String. take a console.log(city) to see what's inside.